# Evaluar en JSF 2.X un BigDecimal a null

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Tengo mi clase donde declaro mi lista de elementos numéricos:

```
@ManagedBean(name="claseView")
@ViewScoped
public class ClaseView implements Serializable {

    ArrayList<BigDecimal> list2 = new ArrayList<>();

    public ArrayList<BigDecimal> getList2() {
            return list2;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        list2.add(new BigDecimal(13.8));
        list2.add(new BigDecimal(135122161211.888));
        list2.add(null);
        list2.add(null);
        list2.add(null);
        list2.add(null);

    }

}
```

En la web estoy intentando evaluar cuando un elemento de la lista viene a `null`.

```
<ui:repeat value="#{claseView.list2}" var="b">
    <p:row><p:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{b}" rendered="#{b ne null}">
            <f:convertNumber type="number"  locale="es_ES" pattern="#,##0.00"/>
        </h:outputText>
        <h:outputText value="Vacio" rendered="#{b eq null}}"/>
    </p:column></p:row>
</ui:repeat>
```

Pero nunca me pinta "Vacio".

He probado a cambiar la lista a `Double`, tambien he probado a usar `rendered="#{b == null}}"`

¿Alguien sabe como evaluar a null?

Comment: Sobra una llave al final de la expresión, ¿es un error del código o lo has introducido al hacer la pregunta? `#{b == null}}`

Comment: @SJuan76 era ese el fallo, gracias.